# Inline Citations and Abbreviation/Acronym locations

Tags: citations

The question I have is two-fold, but it's basically the same question for citations and abbreviations.

Let's say that I'm writing a thesis and I want to briefly mention a term which I hope to define later and which after defining, I'd like to refer to using an abbreviation/acronym. *(Whether this is a good idea is a separate concern...I understand it usually is not)*

**Should I place the abbreviation in parenthesis after I first mention the term, or after I define it (Also the last time I plan on using the term un-abbreviated)?**

I'm also wondering about the same exact question, but for inline citations.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the norms you are willing to follow. According to the APA manual, if you want to abbreviate a term in the text, you have to present both the full version and the abbreviation the first time you use the term.